# How can properly log a record of the Student table with my current AFTER UPDATE trigger?

Tags: mysql, triggers

```html
-- Create the SysLog table

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS SysLog ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SysLog (
  ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  TableName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'The table that is being logged',
  Message VARCHAR(255)  NOT NULL COMMENT 'The logging message',
  Created DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
  PRIMARY KEY (ID)  
    )
ENGINE = InnoDB
 COMMENT 'The system log table' ;
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX SysLog_UNIQUE ON SysLog (ID ASC)  ;


-- Create an after update trigger that creates a record in a new table named SysLog 
-- whenever a record in the -- student table is changed. 
USE College ;

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS  Student_After_Update; 

DELIMITER $$


        CREATE TRIGGER Student_After_Update 
        AFTER UPDATE ON Student
        FOR EACH ROW 

        BEGIN 
        
    INSERT INTO SysLog(TableName, Message, Created) 
          VALUES (Student,  CONCAT('', "Updated ID=" StudentID), NOW());
          INSERT INTO SysLog(TableName, Message, Created)
          VALUES (Student,  CONCAT('', "Updated ID=" StudentID), NOW());
          INSERT INTO SysLog(TableName, Message, Created)
          VALUES (Student,  CONCAT('', "Updated ID=" StudentID), NOW());
      END $$

DELIMITER ;

UPDATE Student 
SET Scholarship=7000
WHERE ID= 2; 

UPDATE Student 
SET Scholarship=9000
WHERE ID= 5; 

UPDATE Student 
SET Scholarship=10000
WHERE ID= 7; 

SELECT * FROM SysLog
ORDER BY ID DESC;
```

Hello Everyone,

I am working on creating an AFTER UPDATE that creates a record in a new table named SysLog whenever a record in the student table is changed, but the problem I am having is how can I properly use the CONCAT statement to correctly output the message of "UpdatedID=X" where X is the StudentID that's being updated in each record? Here is the code I have so far.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there's a comma missing in the CONCAT expression. The purpose of the zero length string isn't clear. It's valid to do that, but it's kind of curious, since there doesn't appear to be any reason for it.

Also, to refer to values of columns that were matched by the UPDATE statement, use `NEW.` or `OLD.` to qualify the column name.

String literals can be enclosed in single quotes. (MySQL does accept double quotes around string literals, as a deviation (extension) to the SQL standard. Other databases reserve double quotes for identifiers. My recommendation is to always use single quotes around string literals.)

And it's not at all clear why the trigger would need to insert three rows into the `Syslog` table.

```
  INSERT INTO SysLog (TableName, Message, Created) 
  VALUES ('Student', CONCAT('Updated ID=' , NEW.StudentID), NOW());
          ^       ^         ^           ^ ^ ^^^^
```

Comment: spencer7593-What do you mean you don't understand why the trigger would insert three rows? How else would I log that three different student's records have been updated?

Comment: @spencer7593- I see now why you don't understand because the trigger creates three different rows for just one student's record being updated. How do I fix this?

Comment: @spencer7593-You are right if I only insert just one INSERT statement in my trigger, it will only produce just three records that's being updated by the UPDATE statements. Thanks